# Sign according RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 standard

Tags: rsa, standards, pkcs1

I'm totally lost with is standard RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5.
I have commands that signs document and checks signature below.

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private-key.pem -out aaa.txt.sha256 aaa.txt
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public-key.pem  -signature aaa.txt.sha256  aaa.txt
```

Does these sign/verify procedures complains RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 standard?

Comment: _If_ `{private,public}-key.pem` are a 'plain' RSA keypair, then **yes** `openssl dgst -sign/verify` (and EVP_PKEY which it uses) [defaults for RSA to 'pkcs1' padding](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rsa/rsa_pmeth.c#L60) which in OpenSSL means PKCS1-v1_5. PS: 'complains' doesn't make sense here and 'procedures' is plural, so it should be: Do these procedures comply to [or with] the standard.